# Limit of Derivative and Derivative of Limit

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Assuming the integral is finite and $f$ is continuous, does this argument always work? If not, what do we need more?

$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{\infty} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t =$
$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \lim_{u\to\infty}\int_x^u f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t =$
$\displaystyle \lim_{u\to\infty} \frac{d}{dx} \int_x^u f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t =$
$\displaystyle \lim_{u\to\infty} (-f(x)) = -f(x)$

Thank you.

Comment: @Simon S: I saw your editing in the third equality. Should $f(u)$ disappear because we take the derivative with respect to x, treating $f(u)$ as a scalar (by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)?

Comment: Ops, you're right. Rolled back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The derivative is in itself a limit. So the problem boils down to when one can exchange two limits. The answer is that it is sufficient for the limits to be uniform in the other variable. In other words, if you're trying to switch order of say, $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\lim_{y\rightarrow b}f(x,y)$, then you need $|f(x_1,y)-f(a,y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$, where $\delta$ does *not* depend on $x$, and similarly for $y$.

On the other hand,your problem immediately follows from linearity of integrals and the fundamental theorem of calculus. Afterall, $\int_x^\infty f(t)dt=\int_x^yf(t)dt+\int_y^\infty f(t)dt$, where $y$ is any fixed number, and the derivative of the second term in $x$ always vanishes since it's constant. So what's hidden in here is that taking a derivative of a constant ensures the two limits commute.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment.