# In what cases are limits interchangeable?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The title pretty much says it all. For some $f(x,y)$, in what cases is it true that

$$
\lim_{x \to a} \lim_{y \to b} f(x,y)=\lim_{y \to b} \lim_{x \to a} f(x,y)
$$

I was able to find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048492/limit-of-derivative-and-derivative-of-limit), but it doesn't quite answer what I'm asking.

Comment: try searching for uniform continuity

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I'm confused as to the connection. Additionally, what if $f(x,y)$ is a discrete function and/or the limits are evaluated at infinity?

Comment: This question comes up in a lot of different guises in various places in analysis, and frankly there is no good general answer, to my knowledge. The "advanced calculus criterion" is that the $y$ limit converges uniformly in $x$ or vice versa. But this is unacceptably rigid in a lot of applications (e.g. interchange of limit and integral).

Comment: @CurtisBechtel For sequeneses you can see [the previous answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/when-can-you-switch-the-order-of-limits). Otherwise can look for [Moore-Osgood theorem](http://www.mathresources.com/products/mathresource/maa/mooreosgood_theorem.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true if $f$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of $(a,b)$, both limits being $f(a,b)$.

Comment: Is this valid for limits at infinity if the function is shown to be continuous?

Comment: @CurtisBechtel, yes. Consider the function $f(1/x, 1/y)$ near $(0, 0)$.

Comment: **If** the function is continuous in a neighbourhood of infinity (in the one-point compactification of the plane).